# ID3 JS Unicode ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, unicode, id3

I have a React Project which has `input type = "file"`
This input accepts music files and I get tags with `ID3 Js` But it returns this.

[image]

How can I convert them to normal view

My code:

```
const tags = await id3.fromFile(file)

console.log(tags)
```

Comment: If you look at the same file with Mp3tag, do you see the unicode characters too or are they a result of your React project?

Comment: I didn't understand how to use this program, but here is the result https://prntscr.com/1qjsr4e

Comment: You have to press ALT + T on your selected track inside Mp3tag. Then you will see all your id3 tags with content. You will also see if the strange unicode characters are saved inside the tag. For example do you see GENRE with "Pop Rock" text only or with all the unnecessary \u0000 code around it?

Comment: https://prntscr.com/1qle2jr

Comment: There are 3 problems: a) The ID3v2 tag seems to be corrupt ("!BAD id3v2") and needs to be fixed first. b) It is not clear if you read ID3v1 or ID3v2 tag with your code line `await id3.fromFile(file)` and c) Maybe you can define something like UTF-8 as option to read your tags?

Comment: to be honest, I didn't understand
a) how to fix it
b) version 2.1.1
c) how is it
Never worked with unicode

Comment: I don't think that this is right place to discuss the basics about metadata in music files, including the fact that there is no ID3tag version 2.1.1., just ID3v1 and ID3v2.3 and ID3v2.4. I suggest that you ask this questions in specialized forums like Mp3tag or MusicBrainz Picard or foobar2000.

Comment: https://prntscr.com/1qm9cf9

Comment: Ok thank you. I will do without music data or find another way

Answer (score 1):

[id3.js](https://github.com/43081j/id3) is able to read ID3v2 frames containing Unicode - see [**/src/id3Frame.ts** line 294 and others](https://github.com/43081j/id3/blob/master/src/id3Frame.ts#L294).

- Your screenshot shows `artist: "M\u0000�\u0000n\u0000e\u0000` while
- the GUI program shows `Måne` (thanks for letting me transcribe everything off pictures).

This means the ID3v2 text frames are in a bad format because

- the wrong [text encoding byte](https://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure) was set (0 or 3 instead of 1 or 2), and/or
- the program who wrote it did not understand Unicode to begin with: `Måne` should be encoded

  - `\x4d\xe5\x6e\x65` in [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (encoding #0) = 4 bytes
  - `\x00\x4d\x01\xfb\x00\x6e\x00\x65` in UTF-16 BE (encoding #1 or #2, as per 2 prefix bytes for a BOM) = 10 bytes
  - `\x4d\x00\xfb\x01\x6e\x00\x65\x00` in UTF-16 LE (encoding #2) = 8 bytes
  - `\x4d\xc7\xbb\x6e\x65` in UTF-8 (encoding #3) = 5 bytes

How about giving us a screenshot of the raw bytes of the entire ID3v2 tag from your music file? The first 512 bytes should be enough. Use a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) to look at the file. A download link to the whole file or its ID3 tags would be even better. Also search in the hex editor for one of the byte sequences I listed - most likely you're unable to find the right spot by just searching for `neskin` (avoid anything non-ASCII).